# How to use Unicode range in C++ regex

Tags: c++, regex

I have to use unicode range in a regex in C++. Basically what I need is to have a regex to accept all valid unicode characters..I just tried with the test expression and facing some issues with it.

---

```
std::regex reg("^[\\u0080-\\uDB7Fa-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+$");
```

Is the issue is with `\\u`?

Comment: Remove `\\u0080-\\uDB7F` and try to match `124`. If it matches, yes, the problem is with `\\u0080-\\uDB7F`.

Comment: The problem is C++ having no usable Unicode support. Use something like ICU.

Comment: Or Boost is also a good alternative. BTW, [check this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript): *UnicodeEscapeSequence* is the letter `u` followed by exactly four *HexDigits*. This character escape matches the character whose code unit equals the numeric value of this four-digit hexadecimal number. If the value does not fit in this `std::basic_regex`'s *CharT*, `std::regex_error` is thrown(C++ only).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew uDB7F and most stuff before that definitely does not fit into a `char`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: That is why perhaps `wregex` could help. I have no time to check that now

Comment: basically what I need is to have a regex to accept all valid unicode characters..The expression provided in the question was just a test regex. I'll modify the question accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work fine but you need to use `std::wregex` and `std::wsmatch`. You will need to convert the source string and regular expression to *wide* character unicode (UTF-32 on Linux, UTF-16(ish) on Windows) to make it work.

This works for me where source text is `UTF-8`:

```
inline std::wstring from_utf8(const std::string& utf8)
{
    // code to convert from utf8 to utf32/utf16
}

inline std::string to_utf8(const std::wstring& ws)
{
    // code to convert from utf32/utf16 to utf8
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "john.doe@神谕.com"; // utf8
    std::string expr = "[\\u0080-\\uDB7F]+"; // utf8

    std::wstring wtest = from_utf8(test);
    std::wstring wexpr = from_utf8(expr);

    std::wregex we(wexpr);
    std::wsmatch wm;
    if(std::regex_search(wtest, wm, we))
    {
        std::cout << to_utf8(wm.str(0)) << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
神谕
```

**Note:** If you need a `UTF` conversion library I used **[THIS ONE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/utfcpp/)** in the example above.

**Edit:** Or, you could use the functions given in this answer:

[Any good solutions for C++ string code point and code unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302279/any-good-solutions-for-c-string-code-point-and-code-unit/43302460#43302460)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! What does the `[\\u0080-\\uDB7F]+` range cover? `A-Z`? In that vein, what would be a regex for `[a-zA-Z0-9]`?

Comment: @SexyBeast I just copied that range out of the OPs question. But you can see what it covers here: http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/character_encodings/PROGRAMMING_character_encodings.shtml Also what you have written should work fine in a regex.