# character and number Persian in regular Expression C++

Tags: c++

I have a a Pattern (in C++, this pattern worked) :

```
(^[ A-Za-z0-9.!@#$%^&*()_+=-]+)\\w+
```

I want supported Persian character in this Pattern for use in C++ not C#

I try follow pattern but not worked :

```
[ آ-یA-Za-z0-9.!@#$%^&*()_+=-]
[ \u0600-\u06FF\uFB8A\u067E\u0686\u06AFA-Za-z0-9.!@#$%^&*()_+=-]
[ \u0621-\u064AA-Za-z0-9.!@#$%^&*()_+=-]
```

can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure if it works here, but this question has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989081/how-to-use-unicode-range-in-c-regex

Comment: @stefaanv it not work

Comment: If you have a problem with making the duplicate Q&A work for you, ask a question about that specific problem. Be sure to produce a [mcve].